# Indexing over all values in nested struct

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a nested struct which contains values and is defined as:

```
mystruct.level1.a = 1;
mystruct.level1.b = 2;
mystruct.level2.a = 8;
mystruct.level2.b = 9;
```

I want to perform operations on the elements in level1 and level2. What I want to do is access the values in level1 and level2, put them in a vector, without referencing the nested field names.

E.g. I'd like to do something like:

```
level1_vector = [mystruct.level1]
```

Which I would like to output:

```
level1_vector = [1 2]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combination of two functions below:

`cell2mat(struct2cell(mystruct.level1))`

Comment: How would I go about returning all values of a? E.g. returning [1 8] in this case.

Comment: I'm sure there is a more straightforward way of doing this using one of the `structfun`, `arrayfun`, or `cellfun` functions, but all I can think of right now to get you going is the following three-liner: `c = struct2cell(mystruct); d = [c{:}]; answer = [d.a];`

Answer (score 0):

There's a `structfun` to do just that. It will return another struct, with the same names. So for your case:

```
con_struct = structfun (@(x) [x.a x.b], mystruct, "UniformOutput", false);
```

Now, `con_struct` will have the same fields as `mystruct`, but instead of a struct, each of them is an array with the values you wanted. You can feed each of arrays again to whatever function you want

```
structfun (@foo, con_struct)
```