# Indexing over a nested structure

Tags: matlab, octave

I believe this is different from [Indexing over all values in nested struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448885/indexing-over-all-values-in-nested-struct) because here I want to output all values assigned to field `value`, outputting `[1 8]`. Whereas in the other question - using the example below - I want to output all values of `a`, outputting `[1 2]`.

I have a struct defined as:

```
mystruct.a.value = 1;
mystruct.a.feature = 2;
mystruct.b.value = 8;
mystruct.b.feature = 9;
```

How would I go about returning all values for the field `value`? E.g. returning `[1 8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `structfun`. It's meant to do exactly this type of things.

```
structfun (@(x) x.value, mystruct)
```

Note that the field value MUST exist in all of the structs inside `mystruct` or it will fail. You should make sure your input is correct.